# Is this good enough to check an ascii string?

Tags: c++

```
bool is_ascii(const string &word) {
   if((unsigned char)(*word.c_str()) < 128){
      return true
  }
   return false
}
```

I want to check whether a string is ascii string.  I also saw such a function to detect whether a string is ascii chars or not:

```
bool is_ascii(const string &str){
         std::locale loc;
         for(size_t i = 0; i < str.size(); i++)
         if( !isalpha(str[i], loc) && !isspace(str[i], loc))
                 return false;
         return true;
 }
```

Which one is better or more reliable?

Comment: The top version only checks the first character of the string. Deviance from ASCII could follow this character and be undetected. The second would fail over a non-alpha, non-space character like a `'1'` in the string.

Comment: Also, note both functions will return `true` if `str` is empty. In the first code, `*c_str()` will return the null terminator, which is 0. In the second code, `size()` will be 0, so the `for` loop will not be entered.

Comment: There’s no way to know from looking at numeric values what character encoding is being used. A character encoding is a mapping between numeric values and characters. Depending on the encoding, a particular number can represent any character or no character. You could determine that the string isn’t encoded in ASCII if you see a value that’s outside the range of ASCII values, but seeing only values that could be ASCII does not show that the encoding is ASCII.

Comment: Probably won't do what you expect on an EBCDIC platform.  (I haven't touched an EBCDIC platform in 30 years.  Likely not relevant for most programs these days unless you happen to be working on big iron.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASCII is a lot more than just alpha characters and spaces.  If you want to accept *all* ASCII, just use your second example and change the `if`:

```
if(str[i] < 0 || str[i] > 0x7f)
    return false;
```

Comment: Alternatively: `if (str[i] & 0x80) return false;` or `if (static_cast<unsigned char>(str[i]) > 0x7f)`.  `char` may be *signed* or *unsigned*, depending on compiler. `str[i] < 0` won't work with an *unsigned* `char` which can't be less than `0`, and `str[i] > 0x7f` won't work with a *signed* `char` which can't be higher than `0x7F`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau yes, one or the other of those conditions will be redundant depending on whether `char` is signed or unsigned.  But the good news is that the comparison works anyway!  And it's easier to understand than bit-twiddling.

Comment: Better: `return std::all_of(str.begin(), str.end(), isAscii);` where `isAscii` Is a lambda for whatever of the excellent solutions above you prefer.

Comment: @Ben there's nothing preventing you from making your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

Other answers get the is-char-ASCII part already. I’m assuming it’s right. Putting it together I’d recommend:

```
#include <algorithm>

bool is_ascii_char(unsigned char c) {
    return (c & 0x80) == 0;
}

bool is_ascii(std::string_view s) {
    return std::ranges::all_of(s, is_ascii_char);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/nKb673vaM

Or before C++20, that could be `return std::all_of(s.begin(), s.end(), is_ascii_char);`.

Comment: I don't quite understand why you need a lambda in the `all_of` rather than directly using the function?

Comment: Good point. I did it to deal with overloading. I changed it to give them different names so it’s not necessary.

Comment: Example: https://godbolt.org/z/qG3E5qMPP => complaint about overload resolution. It can be resolved by passing `static_cast<bool(*)(unsigned char)>(is_ascii)` but yuck: https://godbolt.org/z/KbvEEMWKW. We can write a macro to say "this, but overloaded", but macros are icky: https://godbolt.org/z/xe6fsP4or